# How do I interpret the dissolution rate unit?

Tags: physical-chemistry, kinetics, solubility, solutions

I have found a paper ([link](http://www.karst.edu.cn/en/index.php?c=article&a=view&id=60)) that is interesting for my research project.
The dissolution rate unit in this paper is described as $\pu{mol/cm^2/s}$.

For my project I would need the dissolution speed measured from the surface of the solid (for example $\pu{cm/s}$). Can I calculate the latter from the first?

Comment: I bet you know how to calculate mass from molar amount and molar mass, volume from mass and density, thickness from volume and area. If not, learn it, it is a basic skill.

Comment: :/  mol/cm2/s is actual kinetic unit for scientific experiment. Some cm/s could be used to for bomb fuses or something, and even then only for practical purposes.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The linear dissolution rate can be calculated from molar specific dissolution this way:

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}l}{\mathrm{d}t}=\frac{\mathrm{d}V}{A \mathrm{d}t}=\frac{\mathrm{d}m}{\rho A \mathrm{d}t}=\frac{M\mathrm{d}n}{\rho A \mathrm{d}t} = \left(\frac{\mathrm{d}n}{A \mathrm{d}t}\right) \frac{M}{ \rho}$$

- l is thickness
- t is time
- V is volume
- A is surface area
- m is mass
- $\rho$ is density

Comment: Although this is a problem for the OP (and not you) I don't see how this would be easily implemented, because it requires monitoring the change in A. If you are dealing with a flat surface (as you assume) it is ok, but for a heterogeneous mixture of (say spherical) particles?

Comment: Well, if the dissolution in mol/cm2/s is given.....  I was not addressing how it is being obtained. :-) It was not even asked for. I do agree it may be an essential problem.

Comment: I also agree rough surface would distort calculation, if initial quantity relates to a nominal surface area, while the surface is rough. But it can be considered as the best effort to approximate the value, if no better data are available.

Comment: @Poutnik I belive $M$ should be in the numerator: $dm = M dn$.